# Limit property involved in this equivalence

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory

So, in my textbook, there is this relation that is given without further explaination.

Let consider $A_n$ a sequence of event (probability theory).

If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}A_n=A\text{ then } \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(A_n)=A $

I do not find the limit property that would explain why it does. 
Could anyone help please?

Comment: How is the limit of events defined? When $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq \cdots$ then the limit is defined as the countable union; when $A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq \cdots$ then the limit is defined as the countable intersection. In these cases the claim that $P(A_n) \to P(A)$ can be proved from the probability axioms.

Comment: The limit of events is just defined as $A_1, A_2, ...$. But there are also defining two other sequences $B_n = \lim \sup A_n$ and $C_n = \lim \inf A_n$. Then there is a step where they show what these $B_n$ and $C_n$ are. At the end, they just say, if $\lim \sup A_n = \lim \inf A_n = A$, then $\lim A_n = A$ and if $\lim A_n = A$, then $\lim P(A_n) = P(A)$.